# Overlapping header in ACM SigConf template

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titles, templates, acm

I am using ACM conference template `sample-sigconf.tex` from [HERE](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) for an ACM conference.

The template adds the conference name and author names in the header of the even pages, and the paper title and the conference name in the odd ones.

I have two problems in my script:

1) In the even pages, the template adds a conference name that I did not add and do not know where to edit it. This is it: `Conference'17, July 2017, Washington, DC, USA`. I even searched for this string in the script and did not find it.

[image]

2) In the odd pages, my paper title is long and it may be difficult to change the paper's title. The title overlaps with authors names as shown here:

[image]

Here is the script:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{placeins} 
\usepackage{underscore} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{My Paper Title: A Xxxxxx yyy Zzzzzzzzzzz AAAAA Bbbbbbb Ccccccc ddd Eeeeeeeeeeee Ffffffff Ggggg hhh Iiiiiii}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{First Author Name}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ University}
}
\email{first.second@xyz}

\author{Second Author Name}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ University}
}
\email{first.second@xyz}


\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here. 
\end{abstract}
%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
% 
 \begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Design reuse and communication-based design</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10003107</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Network on chip</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10010560</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~System on a chip</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10010648</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Platform-based design</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Design reuse and communication-based design}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Network on chip}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~System on a chip}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Platform-based design}

\keywords{hardware, design, system}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\section{Research Question}
\lipsum

\section{Methodology}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For shortening the title please use optional text in the title tag, i.e., `\title[My Paper Title]{My Paper Title: A Xxxxxx yyy Zzzzzzzzzzz AAAAA Bbbbbbb Ccccccc ddd Eeeeeeeeeeee Ffffffff Ggggg hhh Iiiiiii}` and the tag `\acmConference` which controls the even side page running head

Comment: If it's the author list that is too long, you can give an abbreviated list like this:  `\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{A. Author, B. Collaborator, and C. Slacker}`

Answer (score 1):

Reference: (https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf)

For question 1, add `nonacm` to `documentclass` to remove `Conference'17, July 2017, Washington, DC, USA.`

i.e., change

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
```

to

```
\documentclass[nonacm, sigconf]{acmart}
```

Edit) Here's the script:

```
\documentclass[nonacm, sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{placeins} 
\usepackage{underscore} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{My Paper Title: A Xxxxxx yyy Zzzzzzzzzzz AAAAA Bbbbbbb Ccccccc ddd Eeeeeeeeeeee Ffffffff Ggggg hhh Iiiiiii}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{First Author Name}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ University}
}
\email{first.second@xyz}

\author{Second Author Name}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{XYZ University}
}
\email{first.second@xyz}


\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here. 
\end{abstract}
%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
% 
 \begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Design reuse and communication-based design</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10003107</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Network on chip</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10010560</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~System on a chip</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
<concept>
<concept_id>10010583.10010633.10010645.10010648</concept_id>
<concept_desc>Hardware~Platform-based design</concept_desc>
<concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
</concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Design reuse and communication-based design}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Network on chip}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~System on a chip}
\ccsdesc[500]{Hardware~Platform-based design}

\keywords{hardware, design, system}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\section{Research Question}
\lipsum

\section{Methodology}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me. Please, could you put a screenshot and a complete code that solved the problem?

Comment: @Sebastiano Sure. Done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration. There is a little error compiling with Papeeria: TeXLive 2019: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape T1/LinLibertine(0)/m/n undefined(Font)`.  Best regards.